# executing mvc controller using either Jquery or Ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to mimic an mvc ActionLink. I want the whole row to be clickable. when the actionlink is clicked, it calls the connected controller and executes the code within. I want my Jquery/ajax call to do the same.

I've tried multiple ways of doing this with no luck. I'm currently at a point where the row is clickable and the Jquery sees that, however the ajax call does not execute. Or, if it does, the controller does not execute correctly

Here is the Jquery code that catches the click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#policyTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function (event) {
        $(this).addClass('primary').siblings().removeClass('primary');
        var Id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
        var url = "/Home/ReviewPolicy";
        var uc = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
        alert("Does the click work? " + Id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/ReviewPolicy",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { Id: Id }
        });
    })


})
```

Here is the controller it is calling:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReviewPolicy(string Id)
    {
        //Declare policyVM for individual policy
        PolicyRenewalListVM model;
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(Id);

        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            //Get the row
            PolicyRenewalListDTO dto = db.RenewalPolicies.Find(val);

            //confirm policy exists
            if (dto == null)
            {
                return Content("This policy cannot be found.");
            }

            //initialize the PolicyRenewalListVM
            model = new PolicyRenewalListVM(dto);

        }

        //return view with model
        return View(model);
    }
```

When the actionlink itself is clicked (It's not here in the code as I didn't see it being necessary for this problem) it fires and everything works as it should, but the jquery call, sending the very same value (Id) does not.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Are you hitting break point in controller action when you do Ajax call?

Comment: I did. It passes through to the controller, but simply doesn't fire in the same manner it does when the actionlink is pressed

Comment: "doesn't fire in the same manner"...what does that mean? What differences are there? Does it execute all the code? Or is there an error? What did you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I would point out that calling a method which returns a view via AJAX does not make a lot of sense...you can't embed the entire view back into your existing page. Normally  methods which are designed to be called via AJAX return either some HTML (usually by means of returning a Partial View, in MVC world), or some JSON data, which can then be used by the JavaScript code when it receives the response. I note also that in your JavaScript currently you are completely ignoring the response from the AJAX call.

Comment: I'm aware I'm ignoring the response back. I have another variation of the same ajax call with the responses back. They provide no solution for me. I understand the typical usage using an Ajax call, but in this case the whole premise is to leverage its ability to call and execute something after. I want the user to not have to click a button. The row itself is the button. That might be weird, but that's the goal

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou using or not using ajax has nothing to do with whether a button is clicked or a row is clicked. you can easily capture the event and manually submit a form just like youre currently trying to manually capture the click event and fire an ajax call. Anyway, as @ADyson asked, please elaborate on "doesn't fire in the same manner". it's hard to help with only that to go on. Is the parameter `Id` not being successfully passed into the controller action?

Comment: I agree, not sure you need ajax for this. You can handle the click event and make it submit a form, or redirect to a URL.

Comment: I don't want to simply redirect to a URL. I can do that already. I specifically need the controller to take the sent parameter so that I can bring back associated data from a different table. I've tried submitting through a form action. sending the ID that way. Again, it doesn't execute. When I say "fire" I'm referring to the ActionResult controllers output. So, yes, GegH, the parameter Id is not being successfully passed on the click.

Comment: I'm not sure any other fashion in which to explain this. When a row within a table, is clicked, I need to send a value(in this case it is the ID of that row) to the controller. I couldn't care less if ajax, jquery, JS, or some other entity accomplishes that task. However, what I've been trying to say is none of those seem to work. When the ID is sent to the controller, the controller then returns a partial view in the next page. When the Actionlink is clicked, it works. When sending via ajax or jquery .post after row click, it does not.